# How to list specific files in a directory?

Tags: python, datetime

My directory is full of log files every three hours. I am trying to recall the last log file (so three hours prior) and this is the code I am using. So if i run the code at 12 pm noon, i am expecting to get [Automation-05102023090000]. I have triple checked the path so i know that isn't the issue.

```
result=[]
path=(r'/usr/local/scripts/Automation/Logs')
time1=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours = 3)
sample=time1.strftime("Automation-%m%d%Y%H*")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, sample):
            result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
print(result)
```

Right now when I run it, comes up blank [ ]

Comment: did you try it with the relevant file type included in the pattern? i.e. `strftime(...%m%d%Y%H*.log)`. You can also try to `print(name)` in your for loop to see what results the `os.walk` is giving you so that you can see what you are trying to match

Comment: Also, assuming the log file is `Automation-05102023090000`, if you ran the code at 11 and get `Automation-0510202308*`, what are you expecting to match?

Comment: As an aside, `r''` strings around paths only make sense on Windows. The meaning of the `r` sigil is that backslashes within the quotes only represent themselves, just like all other characters; but (sane) paths on Unix-like systems don't have backlashes.

Comment: Side note #2, there's [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) in the standard library, which can make things easier when working with paths. In your case, you could e.g. use `Path.glob` or [Path.rglob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob).